# V8 JavaScript stack trace, what do the trailing numbers mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, v8

Alright, so this might be a quick one... I am working in Node.js

I can't seem to figure out what do the trailing numbers in a stack trace mean.

```
at Function.findById (/home/.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:984:15)
```

I am refering to the "984:15"

I can tell the 1st one is the line number, but what does the "15" mean?

Apart from that, I have noticed that often times the line numbers point to something like "Data.js:6:2034" in my application code, only to find out that there is nothing at line "6", and the "2034" still making no sense.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the 2nd number after the colon in a node.js stack trace line mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366207/what-does-the-2nd-number-after-the-colon-in-a-node-js-stack-trace-line-mean)

Comment: Not a complete duplicate id say... I have a sub-issue where I seem to get this very high char number for files with 80 line width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the column number or char in that line.

`Data.js:6:2034` - low line numbers, large char numbers indicate, that this is at least a compressed file (no whitespaces, no newlines etc).

A file like that should be treated with a formatter during debugging, otherwise it will be really hard.

Comment: You mean source maps?

Comment: Would be one solution. I prefer to just reformat those minified stuff during development and re-minfiying it with an ant job during deployment again. faster.

Comment: I seem to get this very high char number and low line number for several of my files in node that I have written myself. When I go to that particular file there is nothing on that line, and the line width is not more than 80 there.

Are my files getting read differently than what I have typed by the V8 engine?

Comment: hmm, maybe a bug in v8

Comment: Oh well... Can't do anything about that then.

Comment: Actually I just noticed this happens only when using the Jasmine unit testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's the character number at that line number